# Dynamic model of a robotic arm

Tags: robotic-arm, dynamics

I have a question regarding the dynamic model of a robotic manipulator. It is commonly written as follows:
$$
\tau = M(q)\ddot{q} + C(q,\dot{q})\dot{q} + G(q) + J^\intercal F_{ext}
$$
From what I have seen, the equation $\tau_{ext}=J^\intercal F_{ext}$ only holds true at very low velocities, so authors usually remove the velocity and acceleration terms and write:
$$
\tau = G(q) + J^\intercal F_{ext}
$$
So my question is, what happens when our task is highly dynamic with high velocities and accelerations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first equation is **always true**. So at high velocities and accelerations, you use the first equation. See [this](https://modernrobotics.northwestern.edu/nu-gm-book-resource/chapter-8-autoplay/#department)
2. At low velocities $\dot{q}<<$ and low accelerations $\ddot{q} <<$, the first two terms are negligible, and thus you use the last equation.
3. $\tau_{ext} = J^T F_{ext}$ is also *always true*. It is the contribution of external forces. See [this](https://modernrobotics.northwestern.edu/nu-gm-book-resource/5-2-statics-of-open-chains/#department)
4. There are control laws, when you want to exert a desired force $F_d$ at the environment, when the end effector does not move (thus $\dot{q}=0$ and $\ddot{q}=0$):
   $$\tau_{control} = J^T F_{d}$$
   and this can be even more precise if you add the gravity term. This leads to your last equation. See [this](https://modernrobotics.northwestern.edu/nu-gm-book-resource/11-5-force-control/)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, (3) is always true even at high velocities, but it is the (4) that assumes a quasistatic condition, right ?

Comment: Yes, but (4) is a control law, it doesn't describe the dynamics. The dynamics are again : $M\ddot{q} + C \dot{q} + G + J^T F_{ext}= \tau_{control} = J^T F_d $ . In quasistatic conditions, $\dot{q}$ and $\ddot{q}$ are negligible, and thus $J^TF_{ext} =\tau_{control}-G$

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you bring all the external forces on the same side i.e., consider

$$ M \ddot{q} + C \dot{q} + G = \tau - J^T F_{\text{ext}} $$

This equation is always valid.

On the right member, there is the net external force acting on the joints (a vector in the joint space).
Vector $\tau$ is the force (or torque for revolute joints) in the joint space determined by the controller. Force $F_{\text{ext}}$ is the force (in the task space) exerted by the hand over the environment (non-zero only if the hand is in contact with the environment). The reaction force, $-F_{\text{ext}}$, is the force (in the task space) exerted by the environment on the robot's hand. Using the concept of kineto-static, we know that we can determine the force from the environment reflected back on the joints (in the joint space) using the transpose of the (Geometric) Jacobian. Therefore, $-J^T F_{\text{ext}}$ is the force on the joint determined by contact with the environment.

If the arm is pushing toward a concrete wall (static situation) the joints' velocities and accelerations are zero, from which $\tau = J^T F_{\text{ext}}$ that is the results you have from the kineto-static analysis. Roughly speaking, the force exerted by the arm on the environment must be exactly compensated by the force (torque) on the joints from the controller.